# Getting Shopify order data with asp.net c# via JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, shopify

I'm working on trying to build a really simple web application that grabs order data from Shopify's API and displays it in a pretty format.

I'm a front-end developer by day, and back in the day I wrote lots of classic asp, but asp.net and JSON are both new to me.

I spent the past weekend scouring the web for any articles that could give me a quick tutorial, or some really simple sample code for how to do the following:

- Make a call to the Shopify API (http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#show) to retrieve an order record
- Convert the JSON response to grab the customer's first name and last name, and make a list of the line items on their order. Then, nicely formatting it and displaying it in html.

I found json.net and I read a bit about the httpclient in asp.net.

Does anyone have any really simple sample code, or any links to tutorials, that a beginner like me could use to learn how to use asp.net c# to pull shopify data and display it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did an integration with shopify. I found the best approach was to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). I believe there might be an open source projects around the Shopify API, but I found that they did a lot of questionable things with the calls/responses.

I created a basic execute wrapper around the RestSharp execute method

```
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient(GetHost());
    if (AuthToken != null)
        client.Authenticator = new ShopifyAuthenticator(AuthToken);

    var result = client.Execute<T>(request);

    if(result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        throw new ShopifyUnauthorizedException(result.StatusDescription);

    if (result.ErrorException != null)
    {
        const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more information.";
        throw new ShopifyException(message, result.ErrorException);
    }

    return result.Data;
}

public string GetHost()
{
    return Uri.UriSchemeHttps + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Store + _shopifyHost;
}
```

AuthToken is the Authtoken for your store.
Store is the sub domain of shopify.
You can cut out the exception propagating stuff, until you have a better understanding.

Also created a basic RestSharp OAuth2Authenticator.

```
class ShopifyAuthenticator : OAuth2Authenticator
{
    public ShopifyAuthenticator(string accessToken)
        : base(accessToken)
    {

    }

    public override void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        // only add the Authorization parameter if it hasn't been added.
        if (!request.Parameters.Any(p => p.Name.Equals("X-Shopify-Access-Token", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            request.AddParameter("X-Shopify-Access-Token", AccessToken, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you have to call is the wrapper method.

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(_shopEndpoint);
return _client.Execute<ShopResult>(request, parameters).Shop;
```

Classes and constants:

```
const string _shopEndpoint = "/admin/shop.json";
const string _shopifyHost = ".myshopify.com";

class ShopResult
{
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Shopify API's shop object is a collection of the general settings and information about the shop.
/// </summary>
public class Shop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's street address.
    /// </summary>
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The city in which the shop is located.
    /// </summary>
    public string City { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's country (by default equal to the two-letter country code).
    /// </summary>
    public string Country { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The two-letter country code corresponding to the shop's country.
    /// </summary>
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's normalized country name.
    /// </summary>
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date and time when the shop was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The customer's email.
    /// </summary>
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The three-letter code for the currency that the shop accepts.
    /// </summary>
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's domain.
    /// </summary>
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The contact email address for the shop.
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Feature is present when a shop has a google app domain. It will be returned as a URL. If
    /// the shop does not have this feature enabled it will default to "null."
    /// </summary>
    public string GoogleAppsDomain { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Feature is present if a shop has google apps enabled. Those shops with this feature
    /// will be able to login to the google apps login. Shops without this feature enabled will default to "null."
    /// </summary>
    public string GoogleAppsLoginEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A unique numeric identifier for the shop.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Geographic coordinate specifying the north/south location of a shop.
    /// </summary>
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Geographic coordinate specifying the east/west location of a shop.
    /// </summary>
    public string Logitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A string representing the way currency is formatted when the currency isn't specified.
    /// </summary>
    public string MoneyFormat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A string representing the way currency is formatted when the currency is specified.
    /// </summary>
    public string MoneyWithCurrencyFormat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's 'myshopify.com' domain.
    /// </summary>
    public string MyshopifyDomain { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the shop.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the Shopify plan the shop is on.
    /// </summary>
    public string PlanName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The display name of the Shopify plan the shop is on.
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayPlanName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the Storefront password protection is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    public string PasswordEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The contact phone number for the shop.
    /// </summary>
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The shop's normalized province or state name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Province { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The two-letter code for the shop's province or state.
    /// </summary>
    public string ProvinceCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The username of the shop owner.
    /// </summary>
    public string ShopOwner { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The setting for whether applicable taxes are included in product prices: Valid values are: "true" or "null."
    /// </summary>
    public string TaxShipping { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The setting for whether applicable taxes are included in product prices. Valid values are: "true" or "null."
    /// </summary>
    public string TaxesIncluded { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The setting for whether the shop is applying taxes on a per-county basis or not (US-only). Valid values are: "true" or "null."
    /// </summary>
    public string CountyTaxes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the timezone the shop is in.
    /// </summary>
    public string Timezone { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The zip or postal code of the shop's address.
    /// </summary>
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```